# Why can't I tap on an UITableViewCell when it is animating between two cell background colors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uianimation

I have an simple animation for changing background colors repeatedly on my UITableViewCell. Here is a snippet of my code. For some reason doing this will not all me to call my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method???? I know this because when I remove the code below, it works fine. Any solutions to this? Thanks!

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell       forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0    options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:3.0/255.0 green:165.0/255.0     blue:136.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }];
 } completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option to your keyframe animation. I tested it, and this works for me:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

         [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:3.0/255.0 green:165.0/255.0 blue:136.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }];
    } completion:nil];
}
```